# Error bound of norms

Tags: numerical-methods

I have to prove the following:
$$|| x_k - x || \leq \frac{||c||^k}{1-||c||}||x_1-x_0||$$
I don't know how to start. I have already proved that $||x_k - x|| \leq ||c||^k ||x_0 - x||$

Can somebody help me please?

Edit:

Here is $c$ an $n \times n$ matrix, and $||c|| < 1$, and $$x_k = cx_{k-1} + z \ \ \ \ \text{for } k=1,2,\dots $$ $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $z$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ aswell. We'll choose $x$ and $x_0$ arbitrary. The norm is just a random norm

Comment: Hi, could you include some details on what the various $x$ and $|| \cdot ||$ are? My guess is that $x$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $|| \cdot ||$ is the usual Euclidean norm?

Comment: I will add some info

Comment: Something wrong with your inequality Letting $\|x\| \to \infty$ we get a contradiction.

Comment: $x$ is supposed to be the limit of $(x_n)$, isn't it ?

Comment: Exactly, it is the limit

Comment: Also if $c$ is a matrix,you should have $\|c\|$ (or $\|c\|^k$) in the inequalities instead. Please review your question if you can edit.

Comment: I have changed it, thank you for mentioning

Comment: Did you give all the information ? I think we should at least have $\|z\|<1$.

Comment: This is all the information I have, the question doesn't state anything about $||z||$, instead $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: You need to have $\|c\|<1$, else the inequalities make no sense (a positive quantity being smaller than a negative quantity).

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2812573/307944)

Answer (score 1):

Prove inductively
$$
\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|\le\|c\|^k\|x_1-x_0\|.
$$
Then apply the triangle inequality for
$$
\|x_n-x_m\|\le\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|.
$$
Insert the bound above and apply the geometric sum identity.

Then consider the limit $n\to\infty$, and why it is applicable.

This is essentially the proof construction for the Banach fixed-point theorem in normed spaces. With some slight modifications it also applies to the same in (complete) metric spaces.