# Prove Jacobi method is convergent for a column SDD matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to prove that the iterative Jacobi method to solve $Ax=b$ is convergent for a strictly diagonally-column dominant matrix $A$.

I have seen this solution [Proving the Jacobi method converges for diagonally-column dominant matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812573/proving-the-jacobi-method-converges-for-diagonally-column-dominant-matrices). However, I would like to know if there's an alternative way to prove it.

For example, this is a proof of convergence for strictly diagonally-row dominant matrices:

> $A=L+D+U$ and the iteration matrix is $B_J=-D^{-1}(L+U)$.
>
> We have $$\max_{1\leq i \leq n} \frac{1}{a_{ii}} \sum_{i=j,j\not =i}^n |a_{ij}|=\alpha<1$$
>
> Then, $$||B||_\infty=\max_{1\leq i \leq n} \sum_{i=j,j\not =i}^n \frac{|a_{ij}|}{|a_{ii}|}=\alpha<1$$
>
> Therefore, Jacobi converges for $Ax=b$.

Is there a way to do the proof in a similar way to this one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving the Jacobi method converges for diagonally-column dominant matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812573/proving-the-jacobi-method-converges-for-diagonally-column-dominant-matrices)

Comment: Can you specify in what sense the existing proof does not conform with your requirements? It specifically uses that the the columnwise dominance factor is less than $1$.